# Solving simple quadratic - Wolfram Alpha confusion?

Tags: quadratics, wolfram-alpha, discriminant

[image]I have the following quadratic

$$(2\sqrt 2 - 2)x^2 + \sqrt8 x + (1+\sqrt 2)=0$$

Now the discriminant of this is $0$, so it has one real repeated root. A plot on Desmos confirms this.

However, Wolfram Alpha displays the following (see image). 
The solution contains $i$ and doesn't agree with what it should be $= -1.707...$

**What is happening?**

[Solution should be as I said above because $x = \frac{-\sqrt8 \pm 0 }{2\sqrt2 - 2} = -1 - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt 2 \approx -1.707...$ after simplifying]

Comment: What image? I don't see one.

Comment: Those are different expressions.  One involves $2\sqrt 2 - 2$ which is positive and the other involves $\sqrt 2 - 2$ which is negative.  So they'll have different solutions.

Comment: No sorry, I've changed it now!!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha tends to do numerical solutions with certain kinds of polynomials and if you look at the imaginary part, it's $10^{-8}$, so it's doing a numerical solution and getting a really small imaginary part. For all intents and purposes, consider it to be pure real.

Comment: $\sqrt{8}^2 - 4(1+\sqrt{2})(2\sqrt{2} -2)= 8 - 8(\sqrt 2 +1)(\sqrt 2-1) = 8 -8(2-1) = 0$ and... wow.... must be some really weird really small rounding error.

Comment: *A plot on Desmos confirms this* --- To me this is like checking that the city has picked up your garbage by looking to see that your garbage can at the end of your driveway is empty, and then confirming that your garbage can must be empty by going online to see if today was a garbage pickup day.

Comment: When I enter `solve (2 Sqrt[2]-2)x^2+x Sqrt[8]+(1+Sqrt[2])=0` into W|A it gives me a single exact solution, as does `roots (2 Sqrt[2]-2)x^2+x Sqrt[8]+(1+Sqrt[2])`. What is your _exact_ input to W|A?

Comment: Bear in mind that WA often gets the Wrong Answer. It is trivial for any real mathematician to perpetually be able to devise a simple limit or infinite series that WA says converges when it actually diverges or the other way around.

Comment: *this is like checking that the city has picked up your garbage* --- Actually this is probably not such a good analogy, since there are many other reasons your garbage can could be empty (neighbor emptied it, the garbage can fell over in high winds and trash blew away and someone later set it back upright, aliens from space took the garbage from your can, etc.). Better would be "this is like checking that your garbage can is empty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That $\pm4.21468\times10^{-8}i$ results from a rounding error and should be seen as $0$. So, the numerical answer is actually $.603553\times(-2.82843)$, which is indeed about $-1.707$.